# Hot to run HTTP server with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create isolated environment to run modified python interpreter in it.
I have docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    cpython:
        image: ubuntu
        ports:
            - "7777:7777"
        volumes:
            - /home/myuser/workspace/cpython:/docker
        working_dir: /docker
        # stdin_open: true
        # tty: true
        command: /docker/python /docker/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -p 7777
```

But when starting `docker-compose up` i get:

```
myuser@myuser-laptop:~/workspace/cpython$ docker-compose up
Recreating cpython_cpython_1 ... 
Recreating cpython_cpython_1 ... done
Attaching to cpython_cpython_1
cpython_1  | Server ready at http://localhost:7777/
cpython_1  | Server commands: [b]rowser, [q]uit
cpython_1  | server> 
cpython_1  | Server stopped
cpython_cpython_1 exited with code 0
```

Why command `/docker/python /docker/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -p 7777` is being stopped? In my host terminal it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not opening an interactive terminal. Try:

`docker run -it -p 7777:7777 -v /home/myuser/workspace/cpython:/docker ubuntu /docker/python /docker/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -p 7777`

Comment: It's better now, pydoc is running but i cant access http://localhost:7777 from my host machine. I have message in browser: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.".